# Grails Difference in grails test-app vs grails test-app -integration

Tags: grails, integration-testing

What is the difference during the integration phase of running grails tests via grails test-app vs grails test-app -integration

I have a set of tests that will pass under one but not the other but I can't seem to find what is different in the integration phase based on the two ways to call it.

Comment: Jeff, by any chance the tests that fail when running grails test-app are using properties from the GrailsConfig class?

Comment: Not that I see directly.

Comment: I had had the same problem with the integration tests when using GrailsConfig, it is like if the unit tests clear the object and the integration ones don't reload it again before starting, so what I did was to use default values and that "fixed" it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

unit tests in grails run without the environment being set up.  There is no database; objects and the gorm are mocked, and you need to do specific things to set up the domain objects for testing.   And you can't do things like test hql based queries (I think that feature might be coming in newer versions of grails)

Integration tests are *completely* different.  You bootstrap code is run, and all db calls go to an actual running database (which you can configure in datasources if you want it to be different).   If you call a service method from an integration test, it will go to the db, with transactions and everything else.  Also, The Spring bean autowiring/dependency injection step is run, so all your services are fully wired up and ready to go.

Thats a general outline, without seeing the tests and the failures, its hard to say whats wrong.

Comment: The problem is tests in the integration phase fail when I start the tests via grails test-app but not when I start testing with grails test-app -integration.  I mostly looking for what is different in the integration phase between the two calls. (I will post the exact error in another question)

Comment: Just a note its not all tests just a few and they were working in a previous version of grails.

Comment: unit and integration testing are completely different phases that are independent.  can you post the failing test?

Comment: Also, the Spring beans are not created and no autowiring dependency injection happens when you run unit tests

Comment: I'm only looking at a set of integration tests I'm not looking at the unit test currently, the exact error happening is posted http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019758/integration-tests-started-to-fail-with-grails-upgrade but on this question I'm really looking for what is different between the integration phase when started with grails test-app vs the integration phase when started with grails test-app -integration

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar problem.
I'm not sure why, but the order of integration tests was different.
This lead to an error during setUp/tearDown. Basically one tearDown had some issues and didn't remove all objects which were created in setUp. This lead to an error in the next test.

Worth checking.

Comment: This is exactly what was happening, it seems the test order changes between test-app and test-app -integration

Comment: But this leads to a simple conclusion: you have something wrong with your tearDown - it should leave your DB in a state from before setUp.

Comment: Yep, for a discussion of the actual problem with the tests see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6019758/integration-tests-started-to-fail-with-grails-upgrade  This question was just around what the actual difference between the two runs would be.