# Integration Tests started to fail with grails upgrade

Tags: grails

I upgraded a grails app from 1.2.2 to 1.3.7 after this upgrade a few integration tests have started to throw the following error the 'validateAndSaveList' is a method on a service used by the service I'm testing. These tests were passing before the upgrade and they will also pass if I run just the integration test phase with grails test-app -integration

> junit.framework.AssertionFailedError:
>   No more calls to 'validateAndSaveList'
>   expected at this point. End of
>   demands.

Code:

```
import com.e.domain.*
import com.e.exception.GORMServiceException
import com.e.controller.SecurityUserCommand



class AccountServiceTests extends GroovyTestCase
{
def accountService

void testRegisterWithMinimumInfo()
{
    def clinic = new Clinic(name:'clinicName')
    def securityUserCommand = new SecurityUserCommand(username:'username', password:"password", confirm:"password")
    def clinicUser = new ClinicUser(firstName:'fname', lastName:'lname', emailAddress:'abc@abc.com')
    clinicUser.clinic = clinic
    //clinicUser.securityUser = securityUser
    clinic.address = new Address()
    //  TODO - JsecUser no longer in use        
    def role = new ShiroRole(name:'TEST')
    //def subscription = ESubscription.findByName('Charter Member')
    def subscription = new ESubscription(
        name:'Charter Member',
        description:'Charter Member',
        periodType:'Monthly',
        numPeriods:12,
        amountPerPeriod:25.00,
        electronicSubmissionRate:0.00,
        accountingRate:0.01,
        numAllowedUsers:4,
        startDate: today -1,
        endDate: today+1
    )
    subscription.save(flush:true)
    if(subscription.hasErrors())
    println subscription.errors
    assertNotNull subscription
    clinicUser.empathicCustomerProfile.subscription = subscription
    def result = accountService.register(clinic, securityUserCommand, clinicUser, role)
    assert result.success
    assert result.clinic.id
    assert result.securityUser?.id
    assert result.clinicUser.id
}
```

StackTrace

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: No more calls to 'validateAndSaveList' expected at this point. End of demands.
 at grails.test.MockClosureProxy.doBeforeCall(MockClosureProxy.java:66)
 at grails.test.AbstractClosureProxy.call(AbstractClosureProxy.java:74)
 at grails.test.GrailsMock$_createMock_closure1.doCall(GrailsMock.groovy:125)
 at com.e.service.AccountService.register(AccountService.groovy:46)
 at com.e.service.AccountService$register.call(Unknown Source)
 at AccountServiceTests.testRegisterWithMinimumInfo(AccountServiceTests.groovy:53)
```

Comment: Please post the code and the stack trace. It looks like the expectations of your mocks are failing

Comment: updated with code and stack trace

Comment: The test will also pass if I run it as grails test-app AccountService but not when I run as grails test-app

Comment: where are you setting up the expectations for accountService.register?

Comment: Nothing is being done besides what you see here and the actual logic in the service.

Comment: check and double check.  the exception you are getting is very clear.  The code is written such that somewhere a mock object was set up with certain expectations, and the code is doing something else.  Maybe you posted the wrong test?

Comment: Thanks I will dig if somewhere a mock object is set up for that would it carry over to the other tests?

Comment: @jeff it should not, unless someone did something silly.  basically the mock expectations are part of the test, so the code where the mocks are set up should be in the test, or possibly test setup method.  since i dont see a setup, or mocks in the test itself, someone is doing something non-standard or you posted the wrong test ;)

Comment: I found in a unit test mocking for that service that once removed it allowed the tests to work correctly. Please post as an answer so I can approve it. Also it seems all mock objects need to be manually removed now.

Comment: @jeff, please use @hvgotcodes in your comments or i wont get a message seeing I have a comment?;)  Im curious, where was the mocking done?  Every test, both unit and integration, should run in isolation -- all mocking should be done in the test methods themselves, or the setUp method of the testcase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this answer comes from working the issue out in the comments:

the exception you are getting clearly indicates that somewhere you have put a mock object in your service, and the service is calling the mock object in a way it was not set up to handle.

Comment: The unit test for a controller did the following actions inside of a test: def dataBindServiceControl = mockFor(DataBindService)
        dataBindServiceControl.demand.safeBind{}
        dataBindServiceControl.demand.extractPhones{}
        dataBindServiceControl.demand.validateAndSaveList{l-> return true}
        def dataBindService = dataBindServiceControl.createMock()
       controller.dataBindService = dataBindService

Answer (score 1):

The root problem as seen from @hvgotcodes is that there was a mock object for the service even though in that given test there was no mocking happening.

This happened in grails 1.3.7

I found a unit test that was doing the following:

```
    def dataBindServiceControl = mockFor(DataBindService)
    dataBindServiceControl.demand.safeBind{}
    dataBindServiceControl.demand.extractPhones{}
    dataBindServiceControl.demand.validateAndSaveList{l-> return true}
    def dataBindService = dataBindServiceControl.createMock()
    controller.dataBindService = dataBindService
```

If those tests were removed then all the integration tests would pass so to solve with out rewriting the tests I added the following to the tear down method.

```
    GroovySystem.metaClassRegistry.removeMetaClass(DataBindService)
```

With this addition the tests are now working correctly in grails 1.3.7